# Does a foreign key always need to have a constraint?

Tags: mysql, database

I know this is an odd question because I've always been taught to use a foreign key constraint. However, I've come across a case where a foreign key reference value must be kept for historic purpose when the reference is deleted.

It is a task management system whereby a task occurrence references a parent task containing the recurrence rule. This parent task can be deleted, but the occurrence itself must remain in tact with the non-existing parent id. If the parent task cannot be found, the system simply returns an error - eg "parent task no longer exist." The reason why the parent id cannot be set to null on cascade is because it is being used elsewhere in the occurrence as an identifying key.

Another example: What about a YouTube video that was removed from a playlist. Similar situation right? It is being referenced in the playlist, but the video doesn't exist, so it returns an error in the playlist instead.

Do I simply not define a foreign key at all and just simply create the parent_id reference column as a normal column? I just want to be sure how this is normally handled when one encounters a case where one table references another, but the former is not constraint by the existence of the latter.

Comment: Technically, the `ON DELETE SET NULL` cause will handle this for you. If your question is theoretical, then: yes, you can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a constraint is just a technical helper to enforce the semantics defined for the database, i.e. "this column contains a number that is not only an `INTEGER(32)` but also an identifier for a record in some other table". As such they're not strictly necessary, but it:

- makes the intention of the field clear (self documentation)
- keeps your data "clean" by preventing incorrect data from being inserted
- gives the database engine a hint concerning the content of the table which may allow the db to perform more efficiently.

That said, the "proper" way to accomplish what you've described would be not to physically delete the parent record in the first place. Instead, mark the parent as deleted. Since you're keeping the record for historical purposes, surely you'll want to be able to know what the parent used to be, even if it's no longer active or valid.

Second option would be to create a dummy "parent record deleted" reference. Whenever you delete a parent, you update remaining references to point to the dummy record instead. At least you wouldn't rely on errors to implement expected and valid behaviour.

Finally, I see no reason you shouldn't be able to set the foreign key to NULL. It sounds like you're using the foreign key as part of the primary key of the record in question ("is being used .. as an identifying key"). This you almost certainly should not be doing, if that's the root cause of the problem, start            by changing that.

Comment: I thought about the soft delete but the parent task can be created by another user. Other users can subscribe to this parent task and so would have occurrences of the task. However, if the original user who created the original task wishes to delete that task, the expected outcome is that it is deleted from the database and the occurrences are kept as a record for other users who have subscribed. I mean is it OK (or even legal) to not delete a record when the owner of the record explicitly requested it?

Comment: I can't set the foreign key to NULL because it gets complicated where the original task is grouped into 5 tiers of sub tasks. These grouping needs to stay in tact in all occurrences - so that is why identifying key is needed.

Comment: Not sure about the second option - it is essentially like the NULL option - due to the grouping issue. But I suppose if I set everything else to NULL except for the id's... it could work? At least it is like a soft delete, without the actual content - then it would meet the owner's expectation on the deletion... a table full of NULL sounds wrong though... I'm gonna have to think about this some more...

Answer (score 0):

> Do I simply not define a foreign key at all and just simply create the
>   parent_id reference column as a normal column?

Yes. At least this is the way I got to know and how we handle this stuff at work.

You might then want to set an index on the reference column.